# How would I use a command line to search through source code in an fpr file?

Tags: command-line-interface, fortify

I'm learning how to use Fortify for a new position. I have NO experience with it whatsoever and am following a manual to get through some training. While the answer to the question is provided, I want to know how to do things for myself. In part of this exercise, the author states he "opened a terminal and grepped through the source code". He also states this isn't the only way to find the information. How would I get back to the source code through a terminal, and what other ways are there of finding the string of information I'm looking for?

I tried doing exactly what the author said. I opened a terminal, tried to get back to where the fpr file was, and grep through it. I wasn't able to find the file, or I was looking in the wrong place, and therefore wasn't able to find the information I needed to analyze the particular issue that the lab is dealing with.

Comment: Welcome, show some code so someone can help.